# tidync() Error in RNetCDF::open.nc(x) : NetCDF: HDF error - R

Tags: r

I have basic experience with R and I'm starting to use it for modulation. I came across an error that I am not able to solve, and would kindly appreciate it if any of you would be of help.

I am trying to read a .nc file, extracted from NOOA databases (https://www.psl.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/db_search/DBListFiles.pl?did=98&tid=91102&vid=1913), with the tidync() function from the tidync package. I always get the following error:

Error in RNetCDF::open.nc(x) : NetCDF: HDF error

I am able to open this same file with nc_open() from the ncdf4 package.

However, following I want to use hyper_array() from tidync() and by opening the file with nc_open it doesn't allow me to use hyper_array(), because of the class of the object.

I believe the error when opening with tidync() has to be with the version or some error from my settings, as other colleagues are using the same code and the same files and it works perfectly for them. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything to try to avoid it being versions errors (as it has happened to me in the past), but still, it didn't work.

Here are my version settings:
RStudio 2021.09.0+351 "Ghost Orchid" Release (077589bcad3467ae79f318afe8641a1899a51606, 2021-09-20) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

I would kindly appreciate it if someone could help me out, either by correcting the error or by changing the class object so I can open it with nc_open and afterwards use hyper_array on it.
Thanks!!

Code used:

```
library(tidync)
library(ncmeta)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ncdf4)

getwd()

oisstfile <- "C:/Users/marta/Documents/Ciência/Doutoramento/Doutoramento_BYT_Marta/R/R_Data/CTI/Guillem/Global_1980_2020/Global_1980_2020/pottmp.1980.nc"

oisst <- tidync(oisstfile)

oisst_data <- oisst %>% hyper_array()

trans <- attr(oisst_data, "transforms")
```

Gives error:

```
# Error in RNetCDF::open.nc(x) : NetCDF: HDF error
```

Comment: Please provide code if you want help correcting it

Comment: Thank you Robert, have added the code